# Create table Routine definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've been using this table **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES** which has the routine definition for procs and functions, i was wondering if there is a similar table for create table and create view routines.

Answer (score 0):

I would just skip using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES entirely. Instead look at [sys.sql_modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It has the ddl for everything you are looking for except tables. But my question is why do you need to find the ddl for all these things?

Comment: I need it because i am dropping all objects in my dev environment for a specific schema and then i need the ddl from prod in order to recreate those objects in dev.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I would suggest using the database scripting options to generate those instead. WAY simpler.

Comment: yeah, that's what i initially thought the only problem was that i would have to go in and manually add a new table everytime someone creates a table in the schema. i was trying to do it in an automated way.

Comment: But why are these objects being created in prod and then moved to dev? That is completely backwards of how this should work. You should be building stuff in dev, generating deployments scripts and then pushing those changes to prod.

Comment: it's because we have a separate dev box that we are trying to rebuild everytime we make changes to objects or add new objects.

Comment: so it would be like 
DEV 1 --> PROD --> DEV 2 or
DEV 1 --> DEV 2 -- PROD

Comment: Why can't you just script those changes like you will do when it goes to PROD? Not really sure why you need DEV databases though. That seems a bit overkill. The deeper we get here the more this is sounding like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.sql_modules` to find the definition of views.  For tables, one option is SMO objects.  The C# example below returns the DDL for a table in the listed database.  This will require references to the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo`, and `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo` namespaces.  `System.Collections.Specialized` is also used, but only for `StringCollection` in this example.  This can be filtered using the `Name` property of the `Table` class as noted below.

```
        //set source server and database using SMO objects
        Server srv = new Server(@"YourServer");
        //for Windows Authentication
        srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
        srv.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 600;

        Database db = srv.Databases["YourDatabase"];

        //configure Scripter for DDL
        Scripter script = new Scripter(srv);
        ScriptingOptions scriptOpt = new ScriptingOptions();

        //this can changed to views, stored procedures, or other objects
        foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
        {
            //check for system objects
            //use t.Name to check table name if needed
            if (!t.IsSystemObject)
            {
                StringCollection sc = t.Script(scriptOpt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    //DDL is here, it can accessed/used as needed 
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
```